# delete only middle elements except first and last element

Tags: prolog

Example; I have a list [1,2,3,a,f,s,h,u,4,5]. I want to delete 2,3,a,f,s,h,u,4 and final result will [1,5]. How do i write predicate in Prolog?

```
delete(A, [A|B], B).      
delete(A, [B, C|D], [B|E]) :-  
    delete(A, [C|D], E).
```

Comment: What about `[a]`?

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to think of sequence based problems like this is with DCG (Definite Clause Grammar) which is a standard part of most of the common Prolog distributions, such as SWI and GNU:

```
first_last([First, Last]) --> [First], ..., [Last].

... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

first_and_last(L, FirstLast) :-
   phrase(first_last(FirstLast), L).
```

Comment: ... DCGs are not yet part of a standard, due to some quite ill-fated political problems.

Comment: @false ah Ok, sorry I misspoke then. More informally, I should say that they're a standard part of popular Prolog distributions such as SWI and GNU.

Comment: it is practically omnipresent

Answer (score 0):

First, this should be a `delete/2` predicate, not a `delete/3`.

The base clause should be a list that has only two members, while the recursive clause should drop the second element, and move on:

```
delete([A,B], [A,B]).
delete([A,_|R], X) :- delete([A|R], X).
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ZEkCs1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use append/3:

```
?- X=[1,2,3,a,f,s,h,u,4,5].
X = [1, 2, 3, a, f, s, h, u, 4|...].

?- append([F|_],[L],$X).
F = 1,
L = 5,
X = [1, 2, 3, a, f, s, h, u, 4|...] .
```

or append/2

```
?- append([[F],_,[L]],$X).
F = 1,
L = 5,
X = [1, 2, 3, a, f, s, h, u, 4|...] .
```

or even a more succint version of @lurker answer:

```
?- [user].
|: ... --> [] | ([_], ...).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- phrase(([F],...,[L]),$X).
F = 1,
L = 5,
X = [1, 2, 3, a, f, s, h, u, 4|...] ;
false.
```